# Could anyone parse this sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> At the time Malthus was writing, the world's population was under a billion, **but the onset of the Industrial Revolution set in train a remarkable swelling of human numbers to more than 3 billion by the 1960s** -- with no sign of any global Malthusian catastrophe.

In the above paragraph, I can't parse the sentence that I've shown in bold. Which is the subject and which is the verb? And what does that sentence mean?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. You might find your question fitting better in at our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes. As you kindly advised me, I found that site and asked there as well. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its exact duplicate was also posted to [ell.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question refers not to a sentence but a clause. The difference being that a clause is separated from the previous part of the sentence by a comma, semi colon or colon rather than a full stop and the conjunction ('but' in this case) starts with a lower case letter.

Having said that clauses have the same structure as sentences and can be parsed.

- The subject is the phrase "the onset of the Industrial Revolution"
- The verb is the phrase "set in train"
- The object is the rest of the clause

The difficulty you had, I think, is that all the parts of the clause are phrases, two of the phrases are long and complicated, and you did not recognise 'set in train' as a verb.  See this link for a definition of 'set in train' http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/set-something-in-train

Comment: You correctly pointed out what I didn't know. The problem was "set in train". I didn't know its meaning. Thank you for explaining in such detail. :)

But I wonder why "set in train" means "to make something start to happen"..